# Jpa Query Doesn't properly work due to multiple joins

Tags: spring, jpa, many-to-many, jpql

I have 4 entities connected with relationships. `CardHolder`, `Card`, `Vehicle` And `CardCategory` entities. I try to make a JPA query in `CardHolderRepository` so to get a card holder back. But method `findByParameters8` in the repository doesn't work.

Please first see my `CardHolder` class Class(i didn't include getters and setters for all the fields) and then the repository.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cardholder")
public class CardHolder implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "middleName")
    private String middleName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "cardHolderEmployeeCode")
    private String cardHolderEmployeeCode;

    @Column(name = "idNumber")
    private String idNumber;

    @Column(name = "passportNumber")
    private String passportNumber;

    @Column(name = "otherCertificate")
    private String otherCertificate;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "amka")
    private String amka;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "vatNr")
    private String vatNr;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "genderId")
    private Gender gender;

    @Column(name = "lastEntranceDate")
    private Date lastEntranceDate;

    @Column(name = "lastExitDate")
    private Date lastExitDate;

    @Column(name = "numberOfVisits")
    private Long numberOfVisits;

    @Column(name = "isVisitor")
    private Boolean isVisitor;

    @Column(name = "isRetired")
    private Boolean isRetired;

    @Column(name = "retirementDate")
    private Date retirementDate;

    @Column(name = "isBlackListed")
    private Boolean isBlackListed;

    @Column(name = "approvedOvertimes")
    private Boolean approvedOvertimes;

    @Column(name = "pin")
    private Long pin;

    //    @Column(name = "vehicleId")
//    private Long vehicleId;
    @Column(name = "streetName")
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "streetNumber")
    private String streetNumber;

    @Column(name = "zipCode")
    private Long zipCode;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "municipalityId")
    private Municipality municipality;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "provinceId")
    private Province province;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardHolderJobId")
    private CardHolderJob cardHolderJob;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardHolderCompanyId")
    private Company cardHolderCompany;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardHolderCompanyDepartmentId")
    private CompanyDepartment cardHolderCompanyDepartment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardHolderCompDeptGrpId")
    private CompanyDepartmentGroup cardHolderCompanyDepartmentGroup;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lastEntranceTerminalId")
    private Terminal lastEntranceTerminal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lastExitTerminalId")
    private Terminal lastExitTerminal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pictureId")
    private Picture picture;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardHolder")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "specialCase")
    private Integer specialCase;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardHolder")
    private List<AccessControlCardHit> accessControlCardHits = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardHolder")
    private List<AccessControlSubject> accessControlSubjects = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardHolder")
    private List<AccessControlTimeReport> accessControlTimeReports = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardHolder")
    private List<Presence> presences = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardHolder")
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardHolder")
    private List<CardHistory> cardHistories = new ArrayList<>();

    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardHolder")
    private List<CardHolderTelephone> cardHolderTelephones = new ArrayList<>();

    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "cardholdertocardholdercategory", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cardHolderId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cardHolderCategoryId"))
    private List<CardHolderCategory> cardHolderCategories = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Card Holder Repository

```java
public interface CardHolderRepository extends JpaRepository<CardHolder, Long> {


    List<CardHolder> findByCardHolderCompanyId(Long companyId);

    @Query("SELECT a FROM CardHolder a JOIN a.cards b LEFT OUTER JOIN a.vehicles c JOIN a.cardHolderCategories d" +
            " WHERE (:name is null or (UPPER(a.name) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(:name),'%'))) " +
            " AND (:cardHolderCategoryId is null or d.id = :cardHolderCategoryId) AND (:employeeCode is null or a.cardHolderEmployeeCode = :employeeCode) " +
            " AND (:companyId is null or a.cardHolderCompany.id = :companyId) AND (:departmentId is null or a.cardHolderCompanyDepartment.id = :departmentId) " +
            " AND (:departmentGroupId is null or a.cardHolderCompanyDepartmentGroup.id = :departmentGroupId) " +
            " AND (:cardCode is null or b.code = :cardCode) AND (:licencePlate is null or c.licencePlate = :licencePlate) ORDER BY a.name")
    List<CardHolder> findByParameters8(@Param("name") String name, @Param("cardHolderCategoryId") Long cardHolderCategoryId,
                                       @Param("employeeCode") String employeeCode, @Param("companyId") Long companyId,
                                       @Param("departmentId") Long departmentId, @Param("departmentGroupId") Long departmentGroupId,
                                       @Param("cardCode") String cardCode, @Param("licencePlate") String licencePlate);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do yu get an error, not the expected result or ???

Comment: findByParameters8 doesn't bring anything back. When i test it searching with name doesn't bring anything back

Comment: Please add that to your question as additional information.

Comment: Many thanks for the edit Mr Deinum!I appreciate it!